# How can I change dynamically class attribute of a Bootstrap Card component in ngFor loop?

Tags: angular, angular6

I would like to display Cards with the suitable class (Danger, warning, info,..) depending the attribute `category.color`?

```
<div *ngFor="let  category of arryCategories" class="col-4 card">
    <div class="card text-white bg-danger mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header">{{category.description}}</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{category.color}}</h5>
            <!-- a><img class="card-img-top" src="{{category.icon}}" alt="Card image cap"></a -->
            <div align="center"> <a id="'{{category.id}}'" (click)="toggle($event)" class="btn btn-primary">select category</a> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directive, it accepts object literal where keys are classes which are added to DOM element if condition evaluates to *true*

```
<div *ngFor="let category of arryCategories" 
     [ngClass]="{'danger':category.color === 'RED', 'warning':category.color === 'ORANGE'}">
</div>
```